# Kendo Ui kendoDropDownList template Text not showing

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a kendoDropDownList column on a grid but I can't get the text of the item to display. It keeps showing the value!

```
          var sexes = [{ "Text": "Male", "Code": "M" }, { "Text": "Female", "Code": "F" }];

          function sexDropDownEditor(container, options) {

                    $('<input required data-value-field="Code" data-text-field="Text" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
                    .appendTo(container)
                    .kendoDropDownList({
                        dataTextField: "Text",
                        dataValueField: "Code",
                        dataSource: sexes,
                        template: "#=data.Text#"
                    });
           }

           $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: dataSource,
                pageable: true,
                selectable: "row",
                filterable: true,
                sortable: true,
                height: 275,
                toolbar: ["create"],
                columns: [
                    ....
                    { field: "Sex", title: "Sex", editor: sexDropDownEditor }
                    ....
                    { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "250px" }],
                editable: "inline"
            });
```

When the row is not being edited I would like the text of the selected item to be displayed but for some reason it displays the value.

Any ideas?

Comment: So when editing the grid row, the dropdownlist works fine, but when not editing you want it to show Male instead of M or Female instead of F ?

Comment: Then you need to use a template on the column. Something like { field: 'Sex', title: 'Sex', editor: sexDropDownEditor, template: #= Sex === 'M' ? 'Male' : 'Female' #

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted this by adding a template to the grid column (similar to the suggestion of Robin Giltner)

```
<script id="sexTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">

       #if (Sex !== null) {#
            #= Sex === 'M' ? 'Male' : 'Female' #
       #}#

</script>

 { field: "Sex", title: "Sex", editor: sexDropDownEditor, template: kendo.template($("#sexTemplate").html()) },
```